# How did this alternation happen?

Tags: english, phonology, germanic-languages

Wiktionary's entry for "seldom" contains the following etymology:

> From late Middle English seldom, alteration of earlier 
>   selden, from Old English seldan (“seldom”), from Proto-
>   Germanic *seldana. Cognate with Saterland Frisian 
>   säilden (“seldom”), West Frisian selden, komselden (“rare, 
>   seldom”), Dutch zelden, German selten, Danish sjælden, 
>   Norwegian sjelden, Swedish sällan, Faroese sjáldan, 
>   Icelandic sjaldan.

The expected form should be "seldon", shouldn't it? I mean, its cognates, as well as its etymon, end with an alveolar nasal. I came up with a few guesses, but the main one is:

• it was a case of "normalizing", associating with words like "kingdom" (ther isn't a lot of words in english that end with "on")

Is it right? If not, how did it happen? Are there any other examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, it's all about analogy, but not with words like "kingdom".

If you are looking for etymology of an English word, the best resource to start your research with is [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/) aka Etymonline which gives a more detailed account of the etymology of English words than Wiktionary does.

As for *seldom*, Etymonline has it [like this](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=seldom):

> Form shifted on analogy of adverbial dative plurals in *-um* (such as *whilom* "at one time," from *while*). The same development also created *litlum* from *little*, *miclum* from *mickle*. German *seltsam* "strange, odd," Dutch *zeldzaam* are related, but with the second element conformed to their versions of *-some*.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!

Comment: As always, Etymonline is plagiarized from the OED (Oxford English Dictionary).

Comment: @fdb - Don't you agree that having English etymologies online for free is better than paying 90 USD a year to read the same in the OED?

Comment: @YellowSky presumably you torrent all your films and music then? The OED ultimately costs money to research, maintain, and collate. It would be lovely if it were available for free but ultimately the money would have to come from somewhere.

Comment: @fdb Etymonline lists their sources - it appears to contain about 80 references to a variety of texts, including the 2nd edition OED (1989) as one of its 24 *primary* sources, but certainly not to the exclusion of others.  Why do you believe it has plagiarized content?

Comment: This is all wrong (and etymonline is indeed a good reference, because in contrast to the OED I may curse it without much backlash). *-n*, *-m* do alternate but there's no free license to say one took precedent over the other. If *-um* is a logical morpheme here, why should it not he original. *Zeldzaam* from *-some* is a red herring, if final /t/ frequently sonorizes (if that's the word for /t/ > /ts/ or anything of the sort). *selten* is distinct from *seltsam* anyhow, which rather implies *idiotic* in the broadest sense, rather *funny [little man]*, or *selten dämlich* (exceptionally stupid)